# How can I throttle the number of commands run inside a bash script?

Tags: bash

Lets assume I have a bash script that executes code like so:

```
for i in $LIST; do
 /path/to/my/script.sh $i &
done
```

As you can see, I am pushing these scripts into the background, and allowing the parent script to execute as many commands as it can, as fast as it can.  The problem is that my system will eventually run out of memory, as these commands take a about 15 or 20 seconds to run each instance.

I'm running one static script.sh file, and passing a simple variable (i.e. customer number) into the script. There are about 20,000 - 40,000 records that I am looping through at any given time.

My question is, how can I tell the system to only have X number of script.sh instances running at once.  If too many are running, I want to pause the script until the number of scripts are below the threshold, and then continue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a follow up...  I'm running one static script.sh file, and passing a simple variable (i.e. customer number) into the script.  There are about 20,000 - 40,000 records that I am looping through at any given time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511884/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260267/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455695/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bash-only solution:

```
MAXJOBS=<your-requested-max + 3>
for i in $LIST; do
 /path/to/my/script.sh $i &
 while true; do
   NUMJOBS=`ps --ppid $$ -o pid= | wc | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1;}'`
   test $NUMJOBS -lt $MAXJOBS && break
done
```

Comment: this is bash, so you can just say `jobs` instead of `ps --ppid ...`.
And `wc -l` is more convenient and more efficient than `wc | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1;}'`

Comment: For me, this ended up being the best (easiest) solution (with mob's tweaks).

Runs pretty flawless, even with a ton of records.

Answer (score 5):

Two tools can do this

(note I have changed your file selection around because I think you should prepare for handling strange filenames, e.g. with spaces)

#### GNU xargs

```
find -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -r -n1 -P4 /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Runs parallel on 4 processors

#### Xjobs

```
find -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xjobs -0 /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Runs on as many processors you have. Xjobs does a better job at separating output of the various jobs than xargs.

Add -j4 to run 4 jobs in parallel

Answer (score 3):

One simple hack is to create a Makefile that executes each of the scripts and run `make -jX`:

```
all : $(LIST)

% : /path/to/my/script.sh
    $^ $*
```

A nice side-benefit is that make will auto-detect when your script has changed, but for this to be of use, you'd have to replace `%` with a template for the name of whatever output file your script generates for a given input parameter (assuming that's what it does). E.g.:

```
out.%.txt: /path…
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use xargs with -P. Structure your script like this:

```
echo "$LIST" | xargs -n1 -P $SIMULTANEOUS_JOBS /path/to/my/script.sh
```

Where of course SIMULTANEOUS_JOBS is how many commands you want to run at once.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the `parallel` command from Joey Hess' [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) package.[*] Usage would be

```
parallel -j MAXJOBS /path/to/my/script.sh -- $LIST
```

[*] Not to be confused with the more powerful, but harder to use, [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel is designed for this kind of tasks:

```
parallel /path/to/my/script.sh ::: $LIST
```

This will run one script.sh on each core.

Watch the intro videos to learn more:

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Answer (score -2):

I always like to do a little recursion for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

max=3
procname="journal"

calltask()
{
    if [ "$(ps -ef | grep ${procname} | grep -v grep | wc -l)" -le "${max}" ]; then
       echo " starting new proc "
       calltask
    else
       echo "too many processes... going to sleep"
       sleep 5
       calltask
    fi
}

calltask
```

Comment: grep returns a non-zero exit status and so does pgrep. There is no need for test, or wc. Also, the regex is very loose in that it can match unexpected things. The best bet here is pgrep if you were to take this (not recommend) approach. if pgrep $pocname >/dev/null; then ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issues with the code. The poster needed to know when a max number of processes was hit, and your example would just check the existence of the process.

Comment: This solution, while it might work some of the time, is problematic. What if the process name is a substring of another process name? Even if you could fix that up with -w or something, what is the op wants to run a process with the same name as other processes? Also, this solution has the very bad property that if the grep fails in the negative for some reason, you will completely bomb the system.

Comment: Youch! You guys are tough. In its defense, a more complex version was used to migrate our entire org, (4000+ users), to Google apps over a one year period. I also use it in https://github.com/speeves/serveradmindowntime which is a command line API browser, (though not in an infinite loop as shown here). Because of its proven track record, I still stand by it.

Comment: "It worked in environment X" doesn't make it good or portable. Lots of bad code might happen work in environment X, that doesn't make it good practice that should be spread to others. The link you have provided is full of bad practices, and pains me to look at. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, jordanm.